# 2D rendering of NRRD volume slicing direction reversed?

Tags: xtk

In the example given at http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/xtk/lessons/tree/gh-pages/13/#run, the Z orientation shows a mirror view of the 3D view. Is there a way to make them the same direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is the same for the red view, and probably for the yellow no ?

I think it's coming from the camera 'position' (0,0,-100). Is that enough for you to rotate the renderer's camera of 180°, i.e. to use ***myrenderer.camera.rotate([900,0]);*** or ***myrenderer.camera.rotate([0,900])*** (I don't remember what is the good one) ?

The issue is the camera is behind the object, not in front of.

Comment: myrenderer.camera.rotate([900,0]) works. Thank you @Ricola3D . BTW, where can I find documents explaining what the number 900 means?

Comment: It's the code that gave me that number : if you parameters's value is distance, the code will rotate of an angle (distance/5 * Pi/180) rad. So for a rotation of Pi, you need distance = 5*180 = 900. The choice of this formula is arbitrary, they saw that with canvas of about n x 100px it gave a ergonomic rotation speed I think.